# Como fazer filtro em LINQ para cada X meses?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Ola, gostaria de saber a melhor forma de filtrar uma lista de objetos usando LINQ em C#, tenho uma lista de objetos chamados de **Medição**, cada medição possui uma propriedade Data, que é a data que foi cadastrada.

O que desejo responder é:

- Verificar a ausência de medições em um determinado mês.
- Se existe ausência de medição em 2 ou mais meses consecutivos
- Se existe uma medição a cada 3 meses(independente do intervalo em dias)
- Se existe ausência de medição em 4 ou mais meses consecutivos

A quem interessar, imagine o seguinte:

```
List<Medicao> medicoes = Banco.CarregarListaMedicoes();
```

O objeto Medicao poderia ser por exemplo:

```
public class Medicao {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime Data { get; set; }
}
```

Quero filtrar a lista acima usando LINQ e seguindo os critérios que passei.
Tem alguma estrutura que facilite isso? Sugestões?

Comment: Coloque um exemplo mínimo dos objetos. http://lorefnon.me/plain-text-table/

Comment: A estrutura do objeto não importa neste caso, pode ser qualquer objeto e o que deve considerar apenas é que possui um atributo Data que é o que vai ser usado no filtro.

Comment: Você só quer verificar se possui algum dos casos? true/false

Comment: Não se trata de importar ou não, a questão é que facilita a resposta veja como [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Exatamente @Randrade

Comment: Essas medições terão alguma data inicial ou final, ou serão aleatórias?

Comment: Adicionei lá uma alteração @rubStackOverflow.

Comment: var listaAusenciaMedicoes = medicoes.Where(x => x.data >= inicio & x.data <= fim).ToList<Medicao>(); Não esqueça do "using System.Linq;".

Comment: As medições são registradas aleatoriamente por uma pessoa, o que preciso garantir é que atenda àqueles pontos, para que não ocorra de passar muito tempo sem registro, o que gera um problema.

Comment: @AndreMesquita Este código resolve o primeiro tópico apenas correto? Como faria de forma enxuta para testar os outros casos?

Comment: Na verdade ele não resolve. Ele está trazendo todas as medições dentro de um período. Ele indica como montar o lambda.

Comment: Entendi, no caso eu preciso na verdade verificar para todos os meses se tem a ausência. Ou seja, se tiver 12 meses que o sistema esta operando, queria fazer uma expressão LAMBDA que verifique para cada mês se tem pelo menos uma medição. Se em todos os meses tiver mas em dezembro alguém esqueceu de medir, então retornaria false para mim.

Comment: Eu não entendi qual é a pergunta. Quer saber qual seria a consulta para atender estes 4 critérios?

Comment: Isso @bigown, não precisa ser apenas uma consulta que resolva os 4 de uma vez, se der bacana, mas se ficar melhor 4 métodos separados também poderia ser. Já me ajuda

Answer (score 5):

Apenas com `LINQ` não é possível, você até pode fazer com `T-SQL`, seja usando `LEAD`/`LAG`, ou utilizando uma `CTE` Recursiva.

Porém apenas com C#, você pode criar um Dictionary, então consultar se em um determinado periodo de meses existe pelo menos uma Medição.

```
public static class Util
{
    private static Dictionary<DateTime, int> qtdMedicoesMes = CountMedicoes();
    private static Dictionary<DateTime, int> CountMedicoes()
    {
        List<Medicao> medicoes = Banco.CarregarListaMedicoes();
        return (
            from medicao in medicoes
            group medicao by medicao.AddDays(medicao.Day * -1).AddDays(1).Today into medicoesMes
            select new {
                Mes = medicoesMes.Key,
                Medicoes = medicoesMes.ToList()
            }
        ).ToDictionary(qtdMedicaoMes => qtdMedicaoMes.Mes, qtdMedicaoMes => qtdMedicaoMes.Quantidade);
    }

    public static bool HasMedicao (DateTime dataInicial, int qtdMeses)
    {
        for (var mes = dataInicial; mes < dataInicial.AddMonths(qtdMeses); mes = mes.AddMonths(1))
        {
            if (countMedicoes.ContainsKey(mes) && countMedicoes[mes] > 0)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Então você vai precisar fazer as seguintes chamadas:

```
public class MedicaoController : ApiController
{
    public bool Verificar(int mes, int ano)
    {
        var mes = new DateTime(ano, mes, 1);
        dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
        obj.AusenciaMedicaoUmMes = !Util.HasMedicao(mes, 1);
        obj.AusenciaMedicaoDoisMeses = !Util.HasMedicao(mes, 2);
        obj.PossuiMedicaoTresMeses = Util.HasMedicao(mes, 3);
        obj.AusenciaMedicaoQuatroMeses = !Util.HasMedicao(mes, 4);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Segue um modo de fazer, lembrando que isso não vai ser muito performático:

```
var medicoes = Banco.CarregarListaMedicoes();
// Customize com a data desejada ou substitua por um DateTime.Now
var data = new DateTime(2016, 01, 18);
var iniciodomes = data.AddDays((data.Day * -1) + 1);
var fimdomes = iniciodomes.AddMonths(1).AddSeconds(-1);

// Verificar a ausência de medições em um determinado mês.
var resultado1 = medicoes.All(medicao => medicao.Data >= iniciodomes && medicao.Data <= fimdomes);

// Se existe ausência de medição em 2 ou mais meses consecutivos.
var resultado2 = medicoes.Where(
    medicao => 
        medicao.Data >= iniciodomes && medicao.Data <= fimdomes
    && 
        medicoes.All(m => m.Data >= iniciodomes.AddMonths(-1) && m.Data <= fimdomes.AddMonths(-1))
);

// Se existe uma medição a cada 3 meses(independente do intervalo em dias).
var resultado3 = medicoes.Where(medicao => medicoes.Any(m => m.Data >= iniciodomes.AddMonths(-2) && m.Data <= fimdomes));

// Se existe ausência de medição em 4 ou mais meses consecutivos.
var resultado4 = medicoes.Where(
    medicao =>
        medicao.Data >= iniciodomes && medicao.Data <= fimdomes
    &&
        medicoes.All(m => m.Data >= iniciodomes.AddMonths(-1) && m.Data <= fimdomes.AddMonths(-1))
    &&
        medicoes.All(m => m.Data >= iniciodomes.AddMonths(-2) && m.Data <= fimdomes.AddMonths(-2))
    &&
        medicoes.All(m => m.Data >= iniciodomes.AddMonths(-3) && m.Data <= fimdomes.AddMonths(-3))
);
```